# How to Pick A Random Word in Javascript

Tags: javascript

This script should pick a random word from the available characters and add it add the end of the url but it doesn't seems to work. Can you identify where I am making the problem??

```
    <script type="text/javascript">
    function randomEI1(len) {
var chars = [ "apple", "google", "ebay" ];
 var string_length = len;
 var randomstring ='';
        var rnum = Math.floor(Math.random() * chars.length);
        randomstring += chars.substring(rnum, rnum + 1);
    }
    return randomstring;
}

var ei1 = randomEI1(1);

document.write('<script type="text/javascript" src="http://www.site.com' + ei1 + '"><\/script>');

</script>
```

Comment: You're calling substring on an array. And you have a } which has nothing to do here.

Comment: I tried indenting your code but it wouldn't indent because it was completely broken.

Comment: chars is an array, you can't really do a substring on an array, because it's NOT a string. You need to pick a random array element, and then do a substring on that, e.g. `chars[1].substring(2,1)` would be `o` because you picked google (chars[1]) and then pulled out a char from that.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

```
function randomEI1() {
   var chars = [ "apple", "google", "ebay" ];
   return chars[ Math.floor(Math.random() * chars.length)];
}
var ei1 = randomEI1();
document.write('<script type="text/javascript" src="http://www.site.com' + ei1 + '"> <\/script>');
```

I'm not sure what you were doing with the len parameter. Does this suit your needs?

Comment: Thanks for the help man. I am a complete noob when it comes to programming. This site is really helpful.